# invalid credentials for user 'monetdb' when using the official docker image and a .monetdb file

Tags: docker, monetdb

## How to recreate my problem

### Creating the MonetDB Container

I have this setup (using windows with Docker Desktop).

Create [the official monetdb docker container](https://github.com/topaztechnology/monetdb) with the follwing **command**:

`docker run -v $HOME/Desktop/monetdbtest:/monetdbtest -e 'MONET_DATABASE=docker' -e 'MONETDB_PASSWORD=docker' -p 50000:50000 -d topaztechnology/monetdb:latest`

**explanation what the command does:**
creates a monetdb container with a database called 'docker' and applies the password 'docker' to the default user called 'monetdb'. It also mounts my directory `monetdbtest/` into the container.

### Testing the container with DBeaver

I test the connection using DBeaver with the following credentials:

```
JDBC URL: jdbc:monetdb://localhost:50000/docker
host: localhost
port: 50000
Database/schema: docker
username: monetdb
password: docker
```

this works fine, i am able to connect and can exequte sql queries with dbeaver.

### Using mclient within the container to send queries

1. 

I enter the container as root with the following command:
`docker exec -u root -t -i nostalgic_hodgkin /bin/bash`
(replace nostalgic_hodgkin with your randomly generated container name)

2.
I navigate to my mounted directory

`cd monetdbtest`

then I test the connection with mclient:

```
mclient -h localhost -p 50000 -d docker
```

I get asked for user and password, so for **user** I enter
`monetdb` and for **password** I enter `docker`. It works and I am in the mclient shell, able to execute SQL queries.

3.
Since I don't want to always enter username and password I create a `.monetdb` file in the `monetdbtest/` directory. It looks like this:

```
user=monetdb
password=docker
```

4. Now I should be able to use the mclient command without entering user information. So I type this command:

```
mclient -h localhost -p 50000 -d docker
```

However I get the message:
`'nvalidCredentialsException:checkCredentials:invalid credentials for user 'monetdb`

---

I did everything according to the [mclient manual](https://www.monetdb.org/documentation-Jan2022/admin-guide/manpages/mclient/). Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to export the environment variable `DOTMONETDBFILE` with value `/monetdbtest/.monetdb`.  See the man page for mclient, especially the paragraph before the OPTIONS heading.

Comment: The [official docker image](https://github.com/topaztechnology/monetdb) does not provide that environment variable. The monetdb docker image is built on top of the Linux Alpine Image. I guess I have to somehow set it inside the Alpine container. Not sure how to do that.

Also I believe this environment variable should not be required. The [manual](https://www.monetdb.org/documentation-Jan2022/admin-guide/manpages/mclient/) says "...If unset, mclient first looks for a file .monetdb in the current working directory...".